# Is any Python type whose objects contain elements that are numbered called a sequence type?

Tags: python

I've been confused about that question for a long time. Is any Python type whose objects contain elements that are numbered called a sequence type?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange should answer your question. Everything that has sequence-like behavior (as following the specified protocol) is a sequence type. If it looks like a sequence, it's a sequence. Hello Duck Typing

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sequences in python are Containers (i.e. they have a `__contains__` method), are Iterable (i.e. they have a `__iter__` method) and are Sized (i.e. they have a `__len__` method).  They also have the following methods:

```
__getitem__
__reversed__
index
count
```

these are your basic *immutable sequences*, to be *mutable* they'll also have the following methods:

```
__setitem__
__delitem__
insert
append
reverse
extend
pop
remove
__iadd__
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand

Comment: You don't actually need `__contains__` or `__iter__` - an `__getitem__` that accepts sequence-like indices and eventually raises an exception is enough. `__reversed__` is also optional (`reversed` can use `__getitem__` and `__len__`). `index` and `count` are provided by the built-in sequences, but they aren't required (and, eg, numpy arrays don't provide them).

Comment: @lvc that's very enlightening, thanks.  What are sequence-like indices?  I assume they must have `__add__`, `__neg__`, `__cmp__` (and I guess `__mul__` for extended slices or can they get by with just addition?)  Anything else (or less)?

Comment: Sequence like indices are the ints in `range(len(mysequence))`. The default itertion behaviour does effectively `for i on it.count(0): yield mysequence[i]`, stopping when one of them is an error. Reverse iteration uses a similar strategy except it starts at the end (so it needs `len(mysequence)` to work) and decerements until 0. I believe it carefully avoids making assumptions about whether negative indices will work.

Answer (score 3):

A sequence is a type that follows the sequence protocol. That implies not just that indices are numeric, but that they are consecutive, start at zero, and iterating yields elements in order of increasing index, and that `len(my_sequence)` works. In practice, this means they need to implement `__getitem__` and `__len__` methods appropriately. From there, Python can "fill in the blanks" so that iteration, `x in my_sequence` and `reversed(my_sequence)` all work without implementing the associated methods - but they might still choose to implement those, particularly if they can provide a more efficient implementation (for example, the default iteration behaviour is as if `__iter__` just tried `self[i]` from `i=0` until it hits an `IndexError`, which isn't ideal for a linked list).

Comment: And they have a length. `__len__` and `__getitem__` both must be implemented.